# Paged Micronaut http client

Tags: java, kotlin, pagination, http-headers, micronaut

Have spent the better part of a day looking for a nice way to read `Link` header from Micronaut's `HttpResponse` using a declarative client. Have a working solution, but feels like there should be something better...

Pre-req:

- Micronaut version 3.9.3
- Api that returns paged data
- `Link` header contains information on first, last, next, and prev pages
- Micronaut declarative client to call said api
- Wish to get all pages from api using declarative client

Example api response `Link` header:
`Link: <my/api/path?page=1&per_page=50>; rel="first", <my/api/path?page=2&per_page=50>; rel="next", <my/api/path?page=3&per_page=50>; rel="prev", <my/api/path?page=4&per_page=50>; rel="last"`

Current setup:

- client:

```kotlin
@Client("my-client")
@Headers(
  value = [
    Header(name = "content-type", value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON),
    Header(name = "x-api-key", value = "\${api.key}"),
  ]
)
interface TestClient {
  // per page included in my-path value
  @Get("\${my-path}")
  suspend fun getData(@QueryValue page: Int): HttpResponse<List<Any>>
}
```

- service:

```kotlin
@Singleton
class TestService(private val testClient: TestClient) {
  suspend fun getAllData(): List<Any> {
    val results = mutableListOf<Any>()
    var page = 1
    var hasNextPage = true

    // Want to replace this if possible
    while (hasNextPage) {
      val response = testClient.getData(page)
      results.addAll(response.body()!!)
      page++
      hasNextPage = response.header(HttpHeaders.LINK)?.contains("next") == true
    }

    return results
  }
}
```

This all works, but the `response.header(HttpHeaders.LINK)?.contains("next") == true` feels weird to say the least. Seeing as there are ways to make paginated endpoints, it feels like there should also be ways to make paginated clients in a more "Micronauty" way. Ideal solution would probably be some way to mark this client as pageable or be able to actually read the `Link` header into some data type that is already provided via Micronaut or somer other common dep and not need to parse it ourselves. Seems there are quite a handful of other threads/questions around deserializing `Link` headers as well, so something else to definitely look into...